# twice differentiable function definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following is the definition of twice differentiable function from a class I'm taking:
Definition: A function is twice differentiable if its Hessian exists at each point in dom(f), and dom(f) is open.
My question is why this definition is not 'if and only if'. Does that mean a function can be twice differentiable even if it does not have Hessian?

Comment: All definitions in Mathematics are if and only if statements.